# Changing selection Manytomany field in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a ManyToManyField named `alphabet`, which contains fields A, B, C and D - whether selected or unselected. How would it be possible to change queries that have selected letter 'A' into 'B'?

```
class Alphabet(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    letter = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.letter

class Chapter(models.Model):
    letter = models.ManyToManyField(Alphabet, blank=True)

class Section(models.Model):
    def somefunction:
        jobs = Chapter.objects.filter(letter__letter='A')
        for i in jobs:
            #change those selected with A to B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to change the Chapter objects with letter A to B for example? Try using [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update).

```
jobs = Chapter.objects.filter(letter__letter='A')
jobs.update(letter=Alphabet.objects.get(letter='B'))
```